# .htaccess (with rewrite for https) Causing infinite loop in Wordpress but only for Feed

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, https

I have a Wordpress site that is forced to https using a .htaccess redirect for anything coming from port 80. Simply marking the Wordpress site URL as https://domain.com does not seem to work - hence the .htaccess fix.

However, it gets into an infinite loop when I try access the feed. Is there any way I can adjust this so that it doesn't redirect the feed to https? From what I understand of Wordpress the '/feed/' is handled with a redirect in the .htaccess already.

The current code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If I move the https/port80 redirect to after the Wordpress redirect then the feed works but then the majority of links/pages aren't redirected to https.

I've tried all sorts but have admitted defeat. I need an apache / htaccess / wordpress expert!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure home and site URL are both https in WP permalinks?

Comment: Yes. Settings > General both 'WordPress Address (URL)' and 'Site Address (URL)' are https://domain.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond  %{THE_REQUEST} !/feed [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also make sure to test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Thank you. Now that almost worked - the feed was showing but all other pages were going into a loop.

I added the port 80 condition so the middle is now:

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80`
`RewriteCond  %{THE_REQUEST} !/feed [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^ https://loveourcaravans.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]`


Sorry, I can't get the formatting correct... If you want to update your answer I will mark it as the accepted one. Thanks.